# Continue to run the Python code however the value of CSV cell is null

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, csv, reader

I have a csv file with below format as a sample, as you see it is possible to have one message or 2 messages,

```
Sara,27,Message1,Message2
Joe,21,Message3
```

I write my reader as below, It works fine with Sara with 2 messages but for Joe with one message the code wouldn't be run. would you mind please have a look and help me?

```
     reader = csv.reader(f)
        try:
            for row in reader:
                name=row[0]
                age=row[1]
                MSG1=row[2]
                MSG2=row[3]
#for row[2]
                if MSG1=='Message1': 
                     print("A")
                if MSG1=='Message3': 
                     print("B")
#for row[3]
                if MSG2=='Message2': 
                     print("C")

        except IndexError:
            pass
```

**Above Code Result:**

```
AB
```

**Expected Result:**

```
AB 
C
```

Comment: check the length of the `row` before accessing the elements

Comment: @deadshot: would you help me alittle more? I check the length of row[3]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you handle errors in the wrong place. Since the `except` is outside of the `for` loop, the error will be handled but the for loop will not continue. Try putting error handling within the loop:

```
import csv

with open('test.dat') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        name = row[0]
        age = row[1]
        MSG1 = row[2]
        try:
            MSG2 = row[3]
        except IndexError:
            # Handling only row[3] and not skipping
            # the row
            MSG2 = "MISSING DATA"
            
        #for row[2]
        if MSG1=='Message1': 
            print("A", end='')
        if MSG1=='Message3': 
            print("B", end='')
        #for row[3]
        if MSG2=='Message2': 
            print("C", end='')
        
        # Add end of line
        print("")
```

UPDATE 1:

- The second issue was that line 2 will not be processed since it will throw exception and be skipped
- In this version the exception is only handling MSG2. Any other error will crash the script (like empty line at the end of the file or missing row[2])

The prints are a bit out of order and the output it gives is:

```
AC
B
```

But this is easy to tweak.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the error you are getting. I didn't run the code above - doing it now...

Comment: I am getting no error unfortunetly. just i think it passes the line relative to C. Just AB is printing not C. I want to also print C.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) and for checking conditions you can use dictionary like this `{'Message1': 'A', 'Message2': 'C', 'Message3': 'B'}`

```
with open('data.csv') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    d = {'Message1': 'A', 'Message2': 'C', 'Message3': 'B'}
    for row in reader:
        name, age, *messages = row
        for msg in messages:
            print(d[msg], end='')
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you perhaps tried reading the CSV into a Pandas DataFrame and then processing the data further from there?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(f)

for index,element in df:
   print(element)
```

element will print all available columns within the CSV.  You can then use another for loop to reference each element and conduct further processing/manipulation